# How to compile my spellcheck script faster? My current scripts takes too much of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spell-checking

I have data set which has like 154,051 rows in it and 13 columns. One of the column has text. I would like to find out frequently occurring words. I wanted to make sure the spelling are correct. So I ran the following script but it takes too much time and it is still running. Is there a way I can run this much faster?

```
import pandas as pd
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

df = pd.read_excel('D:\Text\Text.xlsx')
df = df.astype({"SEARCH_TEXT": str})

mispelled = " ".join(df["SEARCH_TEXT"]).split()

spell = SpellChecker()
eng=[]
for i in mispelled:
    i=spell.correction(i)
    eng.append(i)
```

Can someone please tell me faster way of executing this?